# Python Pandas differing value_counts() in two columns of same len()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame that contains two columns, with trace numbers [col_1] and ID numbers [col_2].  Trace numbers  can be duplicates, as can ID numbers - however, each trace & ID should correspond only a specific fellow in the adjacent column.

Each of my two columns are the same length, but have different unique value counts, which should be the same, as shown below:

```
in[1]:  Trace | ID
        1     | 5054
        2     | 8291
        3     | 9323
        4     | 9323
        ...   |
        100   | 8928

in[2]:  print('unique traces: ', df['Trace'].value_counts())
        print('unique IDs: ', df['ID'].value_counts())

out[3]: unique traces: 100
        unique IDs: 99
```

In the code above, the same ID number (9232) is represented by two Trace numbers (3 & 4) - how can I isolate these incidences?  Thanks for looking!

Comment: Am I correct that you want to find the duplicates? If so, do you want the row number or the duplicated `ID`?

Comment: @MSeifert - Row number would be preferred.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the `duplicated()` function ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html?highlight=duplicated#pandas.Series.duplicated)), you can do the following:

```
df[df['ID'].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

By setting `keep` to `False`, we get all the duplicates (instead of excluding the first or the last one).

Which returns:

```
Trace   ID
2   3   9323
3   4   9323
```

Comment: @ScottBoston But this only checks for duplicates. The OP asks for the number of unique elements of Trace for each ID group. This would return the same ID's with same Trace's but yours wouldn't. I don't think this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` and `filter`:

```
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: x.Trace.nunique() > 1)
```

Output:

```
  Trace      ID
2     3  9323.0
3     4  9323.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#this should tell you the index of Non-unique Trace or IDs.

df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: len(x)>1)
Out[85]: 
   Trace    ID
2      3  9323
3      4  9323

df.groupby('Trace').filter(lambda x: len(x)>1)
Out[86]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Trace, ID]
Index: []
```

Comment: This just returns a df where there are more than two instances of a trace number - not where, let's  say there are two instances of the same trace number, but two [or more] different ID's for that same trace number

Comment: The first groupby checks for duplicate ID, the second checks for duplicate Trace.